# SUM/AVG in SQLITE3 of the last 100 Rows

Tags: python, sqlite

I need to have an avg/sum of the last 100 Rows of a sqlite3-db table.
My idea was to select only the last 100 entries of that specific row by sorting it:

```
    cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(open) FROM eurusd ORDER by rowid DESC LIMIT 100")
```

but that leads to the same result as without any sorting:

```
    cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(open) FROM eurusd")
```

One idea was to enter a WHERE-Clause, but I have no idea how.

I don´t want to be dependend on the actual entry of the rowid, because my code is deleting redundancies (and therefore correseponding rowid's)

I would appreciate any help and ideas!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(open) FROM eurusd WHERE rowid IN (SELECT rowid FROM eurusd ORDER BY rowid DESC LIMIT 100)")
```